# meteor: count with multiple field

Tags: javascript, meteor

i want to count with two field. For example I want to count categories base on years with **this code**. But this code just can count categories only and I want categories can count base on years. For example:-

```
Template.laporankategori.helpers({
  profilcount: function() {

    var subs = {};
 Profil.find().forEach(function(e) {
    if (subs[e.kategori] == null)
        subs[e.kategori] = 0;

    var value = !isNaN(e.amount) ? Number(e.amount) : 1;
    subs[e.kategori] += parseInt(value);
});

    var results = [];
    _.each(subs, function (value, key) {
 results.push({category: key, amount: value});
     });

    return results;

  }
});
```

I expected the result like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfhTZ.jpg)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Could you show some sample data and what you expect the count(s) to be?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I have edit the question.